# How to find the count of users who doesn't have tasks in sequelize

Tags: count, nested, sequelize.js, children, has-many

How to find the count of users who doesn't have tasks in Sequelize.Users and Tasks are different models and  Users hasMany Tasks( foreign key relation )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed following way within single sequelize query

```
UserModel.findAndCountAll({
        offset: 0,
        limit: 10,
        group: ["user.id"],
        includeIgnoreAttributes: false,
        include: [
            {
                model : TaskModel
            }
        ],
        attributes: [
            "id",
            [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("tasks.id")), "taskCount"]
        ],
        having: Sequelize.literal(`taskCount > 0`)
    })
```

This way you can get those users who has no tasks paginatedly and the results `count` property will hold the total number of such users who has no task.